# Данные о загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Возможно ли как-то получить данные об загрузке страницы?

Сколько процентов уже было загружено.

Проблема заключается в том, что на сайте есть preloader в виде спидометра. Нужно сделать так, чтобы стрелка поднималась в точности с загрузкой страницы, например, если сайт уже загрузился на процентов 20, и стрелка должна подняться на столько же.

Comment: Вы поймите, за вас никто не будет писать код, оформите в своем вопросе, минимальный код.

Comment: Мы не можем просто взять и узнать процент загрузки. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958624/get-the-percentage-of-the-page-load-using-javascript